# Trying to importing the data from xml using php to mysql database in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to upload the xml to mysqldatabase using php code. i am struck with the following error..
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml_extract.php on line 12 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml_extract.php on line 12 
getting this error what object should i add in foreach
My xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
    <db>    
    <tb name="data">
        <column name="ID">Rd 1098</column>
        <column name="name">Reynolds</column>
        <column name="header">Its me</column>
        <column name="note">Hi folks</column>
        <column name="roll">3678</column>
        <column name="quantity">45</column>
        <column name="numeric">1</column>
        <column name="price">100</column>
    </tb>
    <tb name="data">
        <column name="ID">RD 8734</column>
        <column name="name">Cello </column>
        <column name="header">Long lasting</column>
        <column name="note">Best in quality</column>
        <column name="roll">24</column> 
        <column name="quantity">87</column>
        <column name="numeric">2</column>
        <column name="price">143</column>
    </tb>
    </db>
```

this is my php code

```
<?php

$url = "D:\\ta.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("new_xml_extract",$con) or die(mysql_error());
foreach($xml -> tb as $row){
$ID= $row->ID;
$name=$row->name;
$header=$row->header;
$note = $row->note;
$roll=$row->roll;
$quantity=$row->quantity;
$numeric = $row->numeric;
$price=$row->price;

$sql = "insert into   'content'('ID','name','header','note','roll','quantity,'numeric','price')" ."values ('$ID','$name','$header','$note','$roll','$quantity','$numeric','$price')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result){
    echo 'my sql error';
}
else{
    echo'success';
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
foreach($xml -> tb as $row){
```

with this one

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//tb') as $row){
```

Comment: ty for the response @Peter Darmis
Now i am getting this error any idea
Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml_extract.php on line 12

Comment: add this just before foreach statement if (!$xml) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the xml document';
    exit;
}

Comment: Getting this error 'Error while parsing the xml document'

Comment: try to alter $xml = simplexml_load_string($data); to  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data) do you still get the same error?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml_extract.php:9 Stack trace: #0 D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml_extract.php(9): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\xml\xml_extract.php on line 9

Got this error

Comment: have your xml string as in the 1st example as here http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php